# How do I prevent users from creating new records of a table in Skygear?

Tags: javascript, skygear

How can I stop users from creating any new records in a specific Table in Skygear JsSDK? Is it possible to do? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Skygear support Record creation access control based on roles. You can restrict specific record type creation by role. It is covered in the guides: [*ACL by Record Type*](https://docs.skygear.io/guides/cloud-db/acl/js/)

The related API reference can be found here: 
https://doc.esdoc.org/github.com/skygeario/skygear-SDK-JS/class/lib/container.js~Container.html#instance-method-setRecordCreateAccess

For role related docs, you will can find in the section `ACL by User Role`.